# How to distinguish between two method overloads both with a ParamArray parameter?

Tags: vb.net, parameter-passing

Having the following method signature

```
Public Sub RareSub(a as string, ParamArray c as string())
Public Sub RareSub(a as string, b as string, ParamArray c as string())
```

What is the proper way to call each overload without confussing the `b` parameter as part of the `c` array?

Comment: since they are all string, I think confusion is inevitable.  how could anything tell if `b` is a `b` or the first item in `c`?

Comment: its like string.Format method Format(String, Object), Format(String, Object[]), Format(String, Object, Object). To Call Format(String, Object[]) you need 4 parameters if not will call Format(String, Object, Object) instead. I use C# but its the same stuff

Comment: the only way is call with names like RareSub(a:aValue, b:bValue)

Comment: sorry in VB its RareSub(a:=aValue, b:=bValue)

Comment: The VB.NET language has rules about which overload is selected, spelled out in detail in the language specification.  As written, the first method will only ever be used when it is called with just *one* argument.  It is therefore not very useful, you might as well remove the c argument.

Comment: You want `RareSub("a", "c")` to call first overload. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I need to call each overload in different situations, and I don't know how to do it.  If it is impossible may be the compiler must raise an error to avoid the creation of an uncallable member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ParamArray` accept array as list of parameter.

If you want use first method(with one parameter and `ParamArray`) then add parameter for `ParamArray` as array declaration

```
RareSub("Value", {"ParamArrayvalue"})
'or
RareSub("Value", {"ParamArrayvalue1", "ParamArrayvalue2"})
```

As mentioned in the comments another overloaded method will be called always when at least two parameters of type `String` will be passed to the method

Answer (score 0):

You need to call with names that way compiler will know the difference

RareSub(a:=aValue, b:=bValue)

Comment: Be aware that the first signature have the `a` and `c` parameters, not the `b` one.  You can't pass a `ParamArray` naming it.

Comment: I know thats because mentioned the string.Format. Each parameter have the same meaning they added a N parameter solution if this its not the case then you shouldn't use this approach